# Extracting GDAL Metadata field but using Geotools in Java with TIFF files

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, metadata

I am trying to extract `Metadata` field from a TIFF file using GeoTools in Java, since I can't use GDAL to achieve that on the deployment platform.

I downloaded a TIFF sample file and used `gdalinfo` command from shell, getting this output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: path\to\file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff
Size is 650, 434
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=/home/user/Desktop/www/file ex/files/grafa/tiff/file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72.009003
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72.009003
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  434.0)
Upper Right (  650.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  650.0,  434.0)
Center      (  325.0,  217.0)
Band 1 Block=650x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=650x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=650x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=650x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

I was able to fetch every other field using GeoTools, but I can't retrieve the Metadata field.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `GeoTiffReader` then you can call [`getMetadata()`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffReader.html#getMetadata--) to get a `GeoTiffIIOMetadataDecoder` which you can use to access those metadata fields.

If you know the exact metadata tags you want to extract then you can look up their TIFF tag codes using a site like https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags.html and call [`getAsciiTIFFTag()`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/imageio/geotiff/GeoTiffIIOMetadataDecoder.html#getAsciiTIFFTag-java.lang.String-) with the code. For example, if you wanted the document name then you could call `getAsciiTIFFTag("269")`.

If you don't care about specific tags or just want to get everything then you can call [`getRootNode()`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/imageio/geotiff/GeoTiffIIOMetadataDecoder.html#getRootNode--) on your `GeoTiffIIOMetadataDecoder` to get an [`IIOMetadataNode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataNode.html) which you can use to traverse the metadata tree yourself. GeoTools provides the [`IIOMetadataDumper`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/imageio/IIOMetadataDumper.html) class that you can use to print all the metadata as XML.